# How to perform CRUD operations on list using buttons and showing every result on popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, button, razor

I have following problem in this MVC Application

My Controller is

```
 public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Employee/
  static EmpUser obj = new EmpUser();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(obj);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {

        Employee EmpD = obj.EmpLi.First(x => x.EmployeeId==id); // with giving values through controller
        return View(EmpD);

    }
```

my model is

```
 public class Employee
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required field")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "id is nedded")]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "in the format date/month/year Ex:31/11/2000")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

public class EmpUser
{
    public List<Employee> EmpLi = new List<Employee>();
    public EmpUser()
    {
        EmpLi.Add(new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "Anuja",
            EmployeeId = "cera122",
            LastName = "Pawar",
            Address = "Indore MP",
            Email = "anu@q.com",
            DOB = Convert.ToDateTime("6/22/1976"),
            Salary = 40000

        });
        EmpLi.Add(new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "Deerghika",
            EmployeeId = "cera121",
            LastName = "Pawar",
            Address = "Indore MP",
            Email = "pawar@p.com",
            DOB = Convert.ToDateTime("7/11/2001"),
            Salary = 7000

        });
        EmpLi.Add(new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "Arnav",
            LastName = "Pawar",
            EmployeeId = "cera123",
            Address = "Indore MP",
            Email = "Arav2@r.com",
            DOB = Convert.ToDateTime("3/12/2010"),
            Salary = 5000

        });
    }
}
```

}

and my view is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Result").dialog({ //dialogize it with JqueryUI
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },` 

 $('#Details').click(function () {
            debugger
            var id1 = $(this).data('id')
            //var id1= $("#Details").val()
            var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Employee", new { id = "_TOREPLACE" })';
            url = url.replace('_TOREPLACE', id1);
            $.ajax({
                url: url, 
                    type: "GET",
                 dataType: "html",
                 cache: false,                   
                 success: function (data) {
                     $('#Result').html(data) 
                     $("#Result").dialog("open"); //open it!
                 }                  
             });
        });
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("EmployeeId")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("First Name")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("LastName")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("Address")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("Email")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("DOB")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("Salary")
    </th>
    <th> OPREATIONS</th>

</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.EmpLi)
{
<tr>
     <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)

    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
    </td>
    <td>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" > Edit </button>|||<button type="submit" value="Submit"> Delete </button>|||
        <button type="submit"  data-id="@item.EmployeeId" @*onclick="Details()" *@ id="Details"  > Details </button>
</tr>
```

}

My problem is when i click on the details button i am just getting first row values in a popup but when i click 2nd row delete its not working

only first row details is working 
others detail buttons not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Here is delete button:

```
<td>
         <a onclick="confirmDelete(@item.EmployeeId);" >Delete</a>
</td>
```

And script:

```
<script>
     function confirmDelete(id) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this item?")) {
        document.location.href = '@Url.Action("DeleteEmployeeById", "Employee")/' + id;
        // Or write delete operation with $.ajax()

        }
    }
</script>
```

**Edit:**

To show employee's details in dialog you can send back data from controller to view with json:

```
 public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        Employee EmpD = obj.EmpLi.First(x => x.EmployeeId==id); 

       if (EmpD != null)
       {
           return Json(new { success = true, id = EmpD.Id, name = EmpD.Name }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
       else
       {
           return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
     }
```

And in your code check result is success or not like this:

```
   if(data.success)
    {
      // take id, name etc.. with data.id, data.name 
      $("#Result").dialog("open"); //open it!
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Model is null");
    }
```

With same way, you can send deleted item's id to view to show in dialog.

Comment: jhoon Bey actually i need details button thanks for the reply

Comment: replace <a> with <button> simply

Comment: i need a employeeId in <script> to retreive the details of id on a popup by a button click

Comment: Do you want to show for example "item with xx_Id is deleted" ? Use onclick for your all operations(details, delete, edit etc.) In that case, you can get id in dialog

Comment: No i want the details of a employee on a popup when i press the details button

Comment: when i pass the parameters onclick function is not responding giving an run time error
thanks

Comment: kk its working in normal return view result rather than using json result
we need pass parameters as 
<a onclick="confirmDelete('@item.EmployeeId');" >Delete</a>
thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

i used 
a on click event in my view 
for details button

```
 <button type="submit" @* data-id="@item.EmployeeId"*@ onclick="Details('@item.EmployeeId')" > Details </button>
```

code for Script of onclick is

```
 function Details(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Employee")/' + id,

                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Result').html(data)
                    $("#Result").dialog("open"); //open it!

                }



            });


    }
```

now every details button view is working

A special thanks to Jhoon Bey